# ¿Error en mostrar indice de series de videos desde la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysqli

> Tengo error en mostrar los resultados correctamente

**Los errores, el problema que estoy presentando**

Obtengo el `id_series` de la tabla serie y mediante el **id** relacionado me muestra los datos de la tabla **chapters.** hasta ahí esta perfecto.

- Serie 2017
- serie 2016

Ahora el problema está en que me muestra los mismos vídeos(video 1, video 2) en ambos capítulos **(serie 2017, serie 2016),**

Para solucionarlo debo pasarle una nueva condición a la consulta no mostrar los mismo vídeos en ambos capítulos, es decir el **video 1, video 2,** debe pertenecer a la **serie 2017,** y en la **serie 2016** no existen capítulos no debe mostrarme ningún indice de los vídeos.

Creo yo que debo añadir el `id_chapters` de la tabla **chapters** a la tabla **videos**

```
id_videos    title_video    description_video      multimedia    id_series    id_chapters
```

El otro error es que en el **capitulo 2** me muestra el botón **+** y este botón no debe mostrarse porque no existen en la columna **description_video** el detalle del mismo vídeo, esta `NULL`

**Estructura de la base de datos**

***Tablas***

series.

```
id_series      title           detail     author
   1        New serie 1      Serie 2017   anónimo
   2        New aventure 2   Serie 2016   anónimo
```

chapters.

```
id_chapters     chapters     id_series
    1          Serie 2017        1
    2          serie 2016        1
```

videos.

```
id_videos    title_video    description_video      multimedia    id_series
   1         video 1        En este capitulo...    video1.mp4        1
   2         video 2         NULL                  video2.mp4        1
```

**Obtengo el `id` de la serie** para mostrar los datos relacionados con la serie.

```
  if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM series WHERE url='".$id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id_series'];
        }
    }
  }
```

**Ejemplo:**

> Muestro en la pagina **estrenos.php** todos los datos de la tabla `series` al dar clic en una de las series, se dirige a la pagina **detalle.php** donde mediante su id muestro los resultados relacionados con el resto de las tablas.

Comment: en tus consultas no usas la tabla **series**, es por alguna razon?

Comment: @juliocpiro es la pagina de detalle, entonces lo único que hago es obtener el id de la serie, mediante el id de la serie muestro los resultados.

Comment: La relacion es asi?  Una Serie tiene Capitulos, y un Capitulo tiene Videos?

Comment: considerando que la relación es así, acabo de dar la respuesta.

Comment: @juliocpiro He editado mi pregunta crees entender ahora, ahora esta clara o no?

Comment: Hola y como hiciste para ingresar la url del video en la base de datos, tienes el codigo por Ahí Bendiciones.

Comment: @Carlos los datos lo estoy ingresando manualmente desde phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indicas, debes corregir la relación agregando `id_chapter` a `video`:

***Tablas***

videos.

```
id_videos    title_video    description_video      multimedia    id_chapters
   1         capitulo 1     En este capitulo...    video1.mp4        1
   2         capitulo 2     NULL                   video2.mp4        1
```

Luego ajustar el query segun ese campo:

```
$get_videos = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id_chapters='".$row_chapters['id_chapters']."'";
```

Para el problema del `+` Reemplaza esta seccion:

```
while ($row_videos = mysqli_fetch_array($run_videos)) {
        echo '<ul class="view">
        <li>
          <div class="rows">
            <div class="play"><img src="../material/moonicon-play.png"></div>
            <div class="video-title"><a>'.$row_videos['title_video'].'</a><span class="toggle"></span>
              <ul class="inner">
                <li>'.$row_videos['description_video'].'</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
            <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        </ul>';
    }
```

Por esta:

```
while ($row_videos = mysqli_fetch_array($run_videos)) {
        echo '<ul class="view">
        <li>
          <div class="rows">
            <div class="play"><img src="../material/moonicon-play.png"></div>
            <div class="video-title"><a>'.$row_videos['title_video'].'</a>';
if(!is_null($row_videos['description_video'])){
    echo '<span class="toggle"></span>
              <ul class="inner">
                <li>'.$row_videos['description_video'].'</li>
              </ul>';
}
echo '</div>
            <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
            <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        </ul>';
    }
```

Comment: No tengo un servidor php donde probar pero tengo una duda para comparar en el IF con el null, actualice a esta *!is_null($row_videos['description_video'])*, si no pruebas con *$row_videos['description_video']!== NULL*

Comment: para el signo `+` agregue una validacion, si el dato es diferente de `NULL` pinta el boton de lo contrario no hace nada. Entonces puse un IF asi: if(!is_null($row_videos['description_video'])){

Comment: he solucionado lo de los vídeos con el ejemplo de la consulta, pero lo otro no comprendo muy bien, el `if(!is_null($row_videos['description_video']))` va dentro del `echo '';` o fuera de el?

Comment: Nada mas que antes lo habia puesto asi con apostrofes y creo que asi no funciona: if(($row_videos['description_video']!='NULL'){ , solo usa el ultimo que puse.

Comment: esta fuera antes cierro el apostrofe y pongo ";" pegare mejor toda esa parte. Ya esta actualizado.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65255/discussion-between-juliocpiro-and-j-mick).

Comment: funciona amigo perfectamente gracias sos un ¡genio!

Comment: Gracias., que bueno que te sirvió,. Suerte